# Layering series in Oracle apex chart

Tags: charts, oracle-apex

I am trying to add two series to a scatter chart in oracle apex 20.1. One of these series is rendered as markers, the other one is rendered as a line. The problem I am having is that the line is always rendered behind the markers, which, due to the amount of data points I have in my first series, completely obscures the line.

I have tried giving the markers a lower opacity to make the line more visible which didn't help, as you can see below. I've also tried changing the series' order which didn't make a difference.

The question I have is: does apex have an option to have the line render on top of the markers?

[Oracle apex badly layered chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjxm2.png)

Edit: changed wording to be more clear

Comment: Two series. I would think of switching their places.

Comment: @Littlefoot that was my first instinct as well. It's what I meant by changing their sequence order. I'll update the question, because I'll admit my wording is pretty unclear.

Comment: Ah. Too bad it doesn't help (and I don't have any other ideas), sorry.

Comment: No problem, at least I've been able to improve the question for others. Thanks for answering :)